# Fetching all the birthdays of users in Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

```
`//now load all my friend's birthdays
    NSMutableDictionary * params = 
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"select birthday, name, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name", 
                         @"query",
                         nil];'

    [self.facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" andParams: params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: self];
```

This only gets me the first friends name. How do I get all the details of the friends?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for `friends_birthday` permission. You won't be able to get the friend's birthday otherwise. It's also subject to the friend's privacy settings - you will only see the DOB if they have made it visible on their profile.

Comment: hi niraj , it is only showing the first of my friends and also his birthday , how do i get all the users birthdays .